# AngularJS: Change innerHTMLl on validation

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, innerhtml

I want to change `innerHTML` of element depending on the result of a validation test. As a newbie to `angular.js`, I am not sure on how to achieve that. I tried to add custom `directive`, but it not works. I want to react on all validation tests for a particular element.  Maybe, someone here can tell me best way to do that.

This is my (not-working) code:

**.js**

```
loginApp.directive('iconValidator', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$validators.iconValidator = function (modelValue, viewValue) {
                if (ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue)) {
                    scope.iconHtml='';
                    return true;
                }
                if (ctrl.$touched && ctrl.$invalid {
                    debuger
                    scope.iconHtml='<i class="fa fa-times-circle fa-lg" style="color:red"></i>';
                    return false;
                }

                scope.iconHtml='';
                return true;
            };
        }
    };
});
```

**.html**

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="signup-form">
        <h2>New User Signup!</h2>
        <form action="#" novalidate method="post" name="regForm" ng-submit="submit()">
            <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" iconValidator ng-model="userName" required autofocus/>
                <span class="input-group-addon" ng-bind-html="iconHtml"></span>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, I included the module `ngSanitize`.

Maybe someone can help me to put an icon in the `<span>` element as the `innerHTML`?

Comment: why not use ngIf or ngShow?

Comment: as I know, then I'll have to write all code in html, I do not want that. I want add code only if it is needed.

Comment: @Edgar so AngularJS is totally wrong for you. It involves writing conditions in HTML, that is just how it works. Without `ng-if` and `ng-show` AngularJS is totally and utterly pointless.

Answer (score 0):

I think better approach would be to use [ngMessages](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages) directive for handling validation error messages.

For example, it can be something like this:

```js
angular.module('demo', ['ngMessages']).controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.submit = function() {};
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular-messages.js"></script>

<div class="container" ng-app="demo" ng-controller="mainController">
    <form novalidate="" name="regForm" ng-submit="submit()">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-group margin-bottom-sm">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="userName" ng-model="userName" ng-minlength="5" required="" autofocus="" />
                <div ng-messages="regForm.userName.$error" role="alert">
                    <div ng-message="required, minlength">
                        <i class="fa fa-times-circle fa-lg" style="color:red"></i> Username must be at least 5 chars long
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok,
I made solution using html:

```
<i ng-if="regForm.userName.$touched"
   ng-class="{'fa fa-lg fa-times-circle': regForm.userName.$invalid, 'fa fa-lg fa-check-circle':regForm.userName.$valid}"
   ng-style="regForm.userName.$invalid ?{color: 'red'}: {color: 'green'}"/>
```

I would like to ask, is it possible to sanitize such html, because same logic will have several components and I do not want to copy past it.